# C#: Check if the shutdown /t xx timer ist active

Tags: c#, windows, timer, shutdown

My goal is to check if there's an active shutdown timer initiated by the shutdown /t xx-command.

I'm programming a small asp.net-website for my personal server use to shut him down.

Shutting it down immediately is not a problem.

But I'd like to check if the shutdown /t xx-command is active, to show a button on the website to cancel the shutdown with the shutdown /a command. This is then useful, when you close the website and return back to have the cancel button visible again.

A lot of questions here only consider the detecting of the immediate shutdown process. So my question is if anybody knows if there's a registry entry or a WMI-Value that I can grab if the shutdown /t xx command was raised. Somehow Windows has to "remember" the time though, when it should shut down itself.

Comment: Have you tried the methods given here: https://superuser.com/questions/1028374/determine-whether-a-shutdown-is-pending?

Comment: Yes, I read it. But this "check shutdown" would always beeing raised, when you enter the website because I prior need to check if a shutdown is active to decide if my cancel button has to be visible. I don't think that this is a nice way to always trigger a fake shutdown and abbort it immediately, when you enter the website.

Comment: The point is that there appears to be no dedicated query mechanism, only heuristics (like trying to schedule another shutdown and see if it errors indicating there is already one scheduled, or scanning the event logs for certain related events).

Answer (score 0):

You can view it with ControlPanel>EventViewer>system.
On my windows 7 , eventid = 1074 for "shutdown -s -t xxxx"

Access the log https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.geteventlogs?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Other way , I would suggest when you run the command, it can be log into your own file or database to keep track.

Comment: Yes, logging it into my database was a thought, but when you run the cancel-command in the windows prompt instead by the website, you will bring the database state inconsistent. I'd like to avoid this when possible. Although the chance that this state will become true is very low, because I'm the only Administrator on my server.

Comment: I will try the eventlog way. Windows is protocolling 4 interesting events: User32: 1074, 1075 and Kernel-General 13 and 12.

Comment: @Sum1Unknown can use power shell to run bash script and insert to database at the same time